# Activity becoming blur

Tags: android

I have a handler in my application which shows a dialog on certain point of time. There is a 20 secs delay for that handler.

I go to Message application and get back to my application, the activity is blurred and has to be force stopped.

What could be the reason for the same?

Comment: Have you dismissed the dialog after you are done with it? If I'm not wrong the call is d.dismiss();

Comment: Yes.. I have dismissed it

Comment: Are you leaving the activity before, after, or while the dialog is shown?

Comment: while the dialog is still showing